# How to access exact same elements using NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, xml, nsxmlparser

I have an XML file I'm needing to parse.  Here it is (stripped for clarity):

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
    <channel>
        <item>
        <title>Yahoo! Weather - Somecity</title>
        <yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:52 am" sunset="5:36 pm"/>
        <yweather:forecast day="Wed" date="16 Feb 2011" low="39" high="59" text="Mostly Sunny" code="34"/>
        <yweather:forecast day="Thu" date="17 Feb 2011" low="29" high="50" text="Mostly Sunny" code="34"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

The problem is, as you can see, there are two `yweather:forecast` elements, and both don't have any static text that can be used to differentiate between the two. Any ideas?

Comment: I know there are similar questions around but they are slightly different in respects.

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem is?  Were I to parse this I might have a class that represents the "forecast" node and simply build an array of them.  To help you we need to know what is not working.

Comment: @Mystik: I just don't know how to deal with two same elements.  I need to grab the elements inside each `yweather:forecast` and add them to separate arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, ended up being quite easy.  Here's what I did:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"yweather:forecast"]) {
    if (counter == 0) {
        TodaysHigh      = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"high"];
        TodaysLow       = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"low"];
        counter ++; //where counter is an instance variable
    }

    if (counter == 1) {
        TomorrowsLow            = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"low"];
        TomorrowsHigh           = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"high"];
        TomorrowsCondition      = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"text"];
        TomorrowsConditionCode  = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"code"];
    }
}
```

Piece of cake, right? :)

Comment: I think you should be packaging the idea of a forecast into a "forecast" object.  This ill alleviate the need to know what is at each slot int he counter.  You could then process a variable amount of days without modifying code.